# Eclipse: Having a make problem when building up the project

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, eclipse-cdt

I have ported my Eclipse project from Ubuntu 16.04, Eclipse version Oxygen to Ubuntu 18.04, the latest Eclipse Version. The tool chain which supported the old program is also installed.

I have ensured that all the environment variables of the tool chain used in the old projects is replicated in the Environment Variable of the new Eclipse. However the following compiler error occurs

```
typedef pthread_mutex_t __gthread_mutex_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         pthread_mutex_init
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:51:9: error: ‘pthread_mutex_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘pthread_mutex_init’?
 typedef pthread_mutex_t __gthread_recursive_mutex_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         pthread_mutex_init
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:52:9: error: ‘pthread_cond_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘pthread_cond_wait’?
 typedef pthread_cond_t __gthread_cond_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         pthread_cond_wait
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:108:1: error: ‘pthread_self’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthrw(pthread_self)
 ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:108:1: note: suggested alternative: ‘pthread_yield’
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:659:19: error: ‘__gthread_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_create (__gthread_t *__threadid, void *(*__func) (void*),
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:659:19: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthrw_’
 __gthread_create (__gthread_t *__threadid, void *(*__func) (void*),
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
                   __gthrw_
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:659:32: error: ‘__threadid’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_create (__gthread_t *__threadid, void *(*__func) (void*),
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:659:32: note: suggested alternative: ‘pthread_yield’
 __gthread_create (__gthread_t *__threadid, void *(*__func) (void*),
                                ^~~~~~~~~~
                                pthread_yield
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:659:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
 __gthread_create (__gthread_t *__threadid, void *(*__func) (void*),
                                            ^~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:660:5: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
     void *__args)
     ^~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:666:17: error: ‘__gthread_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_join (__gthread_t __threadid, void **__value_ptr)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:666:17: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_join’
 __gthread_join (__gthread_t __threadid, void **__value_ptr)
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~
                 __gthread_join
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:666:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
 __gthread_join (__gthread_t __threadid, void **__value_ptr)
                                         ^~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:672:19: error: ‘__gthread_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_detach (__gthread_t __threadid)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:672:19: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_join’
 __gthread_detach (__gthread_t __threadid)
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
                   __gthread_join
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:678:36: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_join’
 __gthread_equal (__gthread_t __t1, __gthread_t __t2)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                    __gthread_join
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:683:15: error: ‘__gthread_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__gthread_join’?
 static inline __gthread_t
               ^~~~~~~~~~~
               __gthread_join
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:696:17: error: ‘__gthread_once_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_once (__gthread_once_t *__once, void (*__func) (void))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:696:17: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_once’
 __gthread_once (__gthread_once_t *__once, void (*__func) (void))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 __gthread_once
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:696:35: error: ‘__once’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_once (__gthread_once_t *__once, void (*__func) (void))
                                   ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:696:35: note: suggested alternative: ‘clone’
 __gthread_once (__gthread_once_t *__once, void (*__func) (void))
                                   ^~~~~~
                                   clone
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:696:50: error: ‘__func’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_once (__gthread_once_t *__once, void (*__func) (void))
                                                  ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:696:50: note: suggested alternative: ‘__unix’
 __gthread_once (__gthread_once_t *__once, void (*__func) (void))
                                                  ^~~~~~
                                                  __unix
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:696:59: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
 __gthread_once (__gthread_once_t *__once, void (*__func) (void))
                                                           ^~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:705:23: error: ‘__gthread_key_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_key_create (__gthread_key_t *__key, void (*__dtor) (void *))
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:705:23: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_time_t’
 __gthread_key_create (__gthread_key_t *__key, void (*__dtor) (void *))
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       __gthread_time_t
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:705:40: error: ‘__key’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_key_create (__gthread_key_t *__key, void (*__dtor) (void *))
                                        ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:705:40: note: suggested alternative: ‘__k8’
 __gthread_key_create (__gthread_key_t *__key, void (*__dtor) (void *))
                                        ^~~~~
                                        __k8
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:705:54: error: ‘__dtor’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_key_create (__gthread_key_t *__key, void (*__dtor) (void *))
                                                      ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:705:54: note: suggested alternative: ‘__wur’
 __gthread_key_create (__gthread_key_t *__key, void (*__dtor) (void *))
                                                      ^~~~~~
                                                      __wur
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:705:63: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
 __gthread_key_create (__gthread_key_t *__key, void (*__dtor) (void *))
                                                               ^~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:711:23: error: ‘__gthread_key_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_key_delete (__gthread_key_t __key)
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:711:23: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_time_t’
 __gthread_key_delete (__gthread_key_t __key)
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       __gthread_time_t
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:717:24: error: ‘__gthread_key_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_getspecific (__gthread_key_t __key)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:717:24: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_time_t’
 __gthread_getspecific (__gthread_key_t __key)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        __gthread_time_t
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:723:24: error: ‘__gthread_key_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_setspecific (__gthread_key_t __key, const void *__ptr)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:723:24: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_time_t’
 __gthread_setspecific (__gthread_key_t __key, const void *__ptr)
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        __gthread_time_t
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:723:47: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
 __gthread_setspecific (__gthread_key_t __key, const void *__ptr)
                                               ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:729:32: error: variable or field ‘__gthread_mutex_init_function’ declared void
 __gthread_mutex_init_function (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:729:32: error: ‘__gthread_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:729:32: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_time_t’
 __gthread_mutex_init_function (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                __gthread_time_t

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:736:26: error: ‘__gthread_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_destroy (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:736:26: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_time_t’
 __gthread_mutex_destroy (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                          __gthread_time_t

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:745:23: error: ‘__gthread_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_lock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:745:23: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_mutex_lock’
 __gthread_mutex_lock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       __gthread_mutex_lock
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:745:42: error: ‘__mutex’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_lock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                          ^~~~~~~

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:754:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘__multc3’
 __gthread_mutex_trylock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                             ^~~~~~~
                                             __multc3
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:764:28: error: ‘__gthread_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_timedlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:764:28: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_mutex_lock’
 __gthread_mutex_timedlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            __gthread_mutex_lock
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:764:47: error: ‘__mutex’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_timedlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                                               ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:764:47: note: suggested alternative: ‘__multc3’
 __gthread_mutex_timedlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                                               ^~~~~~~
                                               __multc3
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:765:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
       const __gthread_time_t *__abs_timeout)
       ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:775:25: error: ‘__gthread_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_unlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:775:25: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_mutex_lock’
 __gthread_mutex_unlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                         __gthread_mutex_lock
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:775:44: error: ‘__mutex’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_mutex_unlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:775:44: note: suggested alternative: ‘__multc3’
 __gthread_mutex_unlock (__gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                            ^~~~~~~
                                            __multc3
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:808:33: error: ‘__gthread_recursive_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_lock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:808:33: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_recursive_mutex_lock’
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_lock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                 __gthread_recursive_mutex_lock
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:808:62: error: ‘__mutex’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_lock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                                              ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:808:62: note: suggested alternative: ‘__multc3’
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_lock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                                              ^~~~~~~
                                                              __multc3
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:814:36: error: ‘__gthread_recursive_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_trylock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:821:67: note: suggested alternative: ‘__multc3’
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_timedlock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex,
                                                                   ^~~~~~~
                                                                   __multc3
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:822:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
          const __gthread_time_t *__abs_timeout)
          ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:829:35: error: ‘__gthread_recursive_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_unlock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:829:35: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_recursive_mutex_lock’
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_unlock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                   __gthread_recursive_mutex_lock
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:829:64: error: ‘__mutex’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_unlock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                                                ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:829:64: note: suggested alternative: ‘__multc3’
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_unlock (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                                                ^~~~~~~
                                                                __multc3
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:835:36: error: ‘__gthread_recursive_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_destroy (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:835:65: error: ‘__mutex’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_destroy (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                                                 ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:835:65: note: suggested alternative: ‘__multc3’
 __gthread_recursive_mutex_destroy (__gthread_recursive_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                                                 ^~~~~~~
                                                                 __multc3
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:850:27: error: ‘__gthread_cond_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_cond_broadcast (__gthread_cond_t *__cond)
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:850:27: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_once’
 __gthread_cond_broadcast (__gthread_cond_t *__cond)
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           __gthread_once
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:850:45: error: ‘__cond’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_cond_broadcast (__gthread_cond_t *__cond)
                                             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:862:40: error: ‘__cond’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_cond_wait (__gthread_cond_t *__cond, __gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                        ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:862:40: note: suggested alternative: ‘lconv’
 __gthread_cond_wait (__gthread_cond_t *__cond, __gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                        ^~~~~~
                                        lconv
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:862:48: error: ‘__gthread_mutex_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_cond_wait (__gthread_cond_t *__cond, __gthread_mutex_t *__mutex)
                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:868:27: error: ‘__gthread_cond_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_cond_timedwait (__gthread_cond_t *__cond, __gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:868:27: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_cond_wait’
 __gthread_cond_timedwait (__gthread_cond_t *__cond, __gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           __gthread_cond_wait
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:868:45: error: ‘__cond’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_cond_timedwait (__gthread_cond_t *__cond, __gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                                             ^~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:868:45: note: suggested alternative: ‘lconv’
 __gthread_cond_timedwait (__gthread_cond_t *__cond, __gthread_mutex_t *__mutex,
                                             ^~~~~~
                                             lconv
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:869:6: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
      const __gthread_time_t *__abs_timeout)
      ^~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:875:32: error: ‘__gthread_cond_t’ was not declared in this scope
 __gthread_cond_wait_recursive (__gthread_cond_t *__cond,
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/gthr-default.h:875:32: note: suggested alternative: ‘__gthread_cond_wait’
 __gthread_cond_wait_recursive (__gthread_cond_t *__cond,
                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                                __gthread_cond_wait

/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/sys/types.h:48:9: error: ‘__ino_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__int8_t’?
 typedef __ino_t ino_t;
         ^~~~~~~
         __int8_t
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/sys/types.h:55:9: error: ‘__ino64_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__int64_t’?
 typedef __ino64_t ino64_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~
         __int64_t
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/sys/types.h:60:9: error: ‘__dev_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘lldiv_t’?
 typedef __dev_t dev_t;
         ^~~~~~~
         lldiv_t
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/sys/types.h:70:9: error: ‘__mode_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__size_t’?
 typedef __mode_t mode_t;
         ^~~~~~~~
         __size_t
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/sys/types.h:75:9: error: ‘__nlink_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__uint8_t’?
 typedef __nlink_t nlink_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~
         __uint8_t



/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/sys/select.h:64:24: note: suggested alternative: ‘FD_SETSIZE’
     __fd_mask fds_bits[__FD_SETSIZE / __NFDBITS];
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
                        FD_SETSIZE
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/sys/types.h:246:9: error: ‘__blkcnt64_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__uint64_t’?
 typedef __blkcnt64_t blkcnt64_t;     /* Type to count number of disk blocks. */
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
         __uint64_t

/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/bits/libio.h:337:9: error: ‘__ssize_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__size_t’?
 typedef __ssize_t __io_read_fn (void *__cookie, char *__buf, size_t __nbytes);
         ^~~~~~~~~
         __size_t

/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/bits/libio.h:362:9: error: ‘__io_read_fn’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__io_seek_fn’?
 typedef __io_read_fn cookie_read_function_t;
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
         __io_seek_fn

/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/bits/libio.h:466:8: error: ‘__ssize_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__size_t’?
 extern _IO_ssize_t _IO_padn (_IO_FILE *, int, _IO_ssize_t);
        ^
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/bits/libio.h:469:8: error: ‘__off64_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_IO_off64_t’?
 extern _IO_off64_t _IO_seekoff (_IO_FILE *, _IO_off64_t, int, int);
        ^
/opt/fsl-imx-xwayland/4.14-sumo/sysroots/aarch64-poky-linux/usr/include/bits/libio.h:470:8: error: ‘__off64_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘_IO_off64_t’?
 extern _IO_off64_t _IO_seekpos (_IO_FILE *, _IO_off64_t, int);
        ^
 /usr/include/c++/7/bits/locale_classes.h:386:12: error: ‘__gthread_once_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__gthread_once’?
     static __gthread_once_t  _S_once;
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            __gthread_once
In file included from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/basic_file.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/fstream:42,
                 from ../src/utility/readpng.cpp:9:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/c++io.h:42:11: error: ‘__gthread_mutex_t’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__gthread_mutex_lock’?
   typedef __gthread_mutex_t __c_lock;
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           __gthread_mutex_lock
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/fstream:42:0,
                 from ../src/utility/readpng.cpp:9:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/basic_file.h:63:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
       __basic_file(__c_lock* __lock = 0) throw ();
                            ^
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/7/bits/basic_file.h:66:41: error: ‘__c_lock’ has not been declared
       __basic_file(__basic_file&& __rv, __c_lock* __lock = 0) noexcept
                                         ^~~~~~~~
In file included from ../src/utility/readpng.cpp:9:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/fstream:107:7: error: ‘__c_lock’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘__c_locale’?
       __c_lock           _M_lock;
       ^~~~~~~~
       __c_locale
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/fstream:1081:0,
                 from ../src/utility/readpng.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc: In constructor ‘std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_filebuf()’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc:80:43: error: class ‘std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>’ does not have any field named ‘_M_lock’
     basic_filebuf() : __streambuf_type(), _M_lock(), _M_file(&_M_lock),
                                           ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc:80:63: error: ‘_M_lock’ was not declared in this scope
     basic_filebuf() : __streambuf_type(), _M_lock(), _M_file(&_M_lock),
                                                               ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc:80:63: note: suggested alternative: ‘_M_seek’
     basic_filebuf() : __streambuf_type(), _M_lock(), _M_file(&_M_lock),
                                                               ^~~~~~~
                                                               _M_seek
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc: In constructor ‘std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_filebuf(std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>&&)’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc:97:5: error: class ‘std::basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>’ does not have any field named ‘_M_lock’
     _M_lock(), _M_file(std::move(__rhs._M_file), &_M_lock),
     ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc:97:51: error: ‘_M_lock’ was not declared in this scope
     _M_lock(), _M_file(std::move(__rhs._M_file), &_M_lock),
                                                   ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/fstream.tcc:97:51: note: suggested alternative: ‘_M_seek’
     _M_lock(), _M_file(std::move(__rhs._M_file), &_M_lock),
                                                   ^~~~~~~
                                                   _M_seek
make: *** [src/utility/readpng.o] Error 1
src/subdir.mk:18: recipe for target 'src/utility/readpng.o' failed
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

08:18:21 Build Failed. 5503 errors, 0 warnings. (took 35s.340ms)
```

Error log reduced to fit word count limits

Steps I have taken to solve the problem

- Check all the environment variables in new Eclipse again
- Look through the build message:

  I found statements like "/usr/include/c++/7/...........", I could not understand why does the compiler path to my host directory instead of the tool chain directory' and I found error linked to glib
- Then I went to my  C/C++ Build >> Settings >> tool settings, I search through each and every includes but it does not path to my host directory
- The only difference I found is that a different compiler is used, I have use the Linux Compiler in the Tool Chain Editor. but I do not see why it matters as I have compiled another cross compile project with other toolchain. They compiled successfully

Am at a loss of what could be the problem? need some direction

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be an old compiler I have..without removing the compiler settings...everything returned to normal it seem but if i removed it in favour of the Linux GCC...all hell break lose